# Piracy site -- obtaining video URLs for Google videos (in a Picasa album)?

Tags: google, video

There's a piracy site that is using (what appears to be) a Google Video CDN (Picasa album?) to host episodes of a television series that they don't have rights to.

(example here: https://www.moviesjoy.net/movie/heartland-ca-season-13-jw8j/2234268-55/watching.html )

There's a lot of obfuscation going on, but if I use the Charles proxy app, I can see that it's calling a URL like this: https://r6---sn-5uaeznkl.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1570202003&ei=c0WXXaD9H8fW1gKF8ovIDA&ip=159.69.35.146&id=8fe5cf330d09870a&itag=22&source=picasa&begin=0&requiressl=yes&sc=yes&susc=ph&app=fife&mime=video/mp4&cnr=14&dur=2649.930&lmt=1569821948294339&ipbits=0&keepalive=yes&sparams=expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,susc,app,mime,cnr,dur,lmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRgIhAJuKXh0GvwhYf_mHuxj44NmLxQpbStUZSVQEYboZ17G3AiEAzIoUWWRDidFtM7okeLWzo_D5gt2F3vi_1s5XB5G7Eu8=&cms_redirect=yes&mip=12.151.99.2&mm=30&mn=sn-

Unfortunately, they've got parameters in there so that it expires after a certain amount of time -- so by the time Google tries to check it, they can't verify the location. I've tried removing the expiration parameter(s), but the URL still won't resolve to the stream.

Is there any way I can provide Google with a working URL structure so they can proceed with takedowns?

Comment: Welcome. The question doesn't look to be a good fit for this site as it's about company policies which is off-topic on this site, anyway, I left an answer with a couple of links. I you requires further help about if there is a site on [se] for this kind of questions, please checkout [meta.se].

Comment: You can just report what you found out and let Google security people handle the rest.

Comment: Ruben and Jan, thanks for the feedback.

I've already filed it with Google's DMCA / legal / abuse page. I've been successful with other sites/takedowns via that method. However, because the link essentially expires between the time I send it and the time they read it, they claim they can't find it. Which is the whole reason the webmaster is doing it -- to make it hard to have content removed. But I'm guessing by removing some parameters or finding the core info, I can provide a URL that is always active to help expedite takedowns.

Answer (score 0):

From [Removing Content From Google](https://support.google.com/legal/troubleshooter/1114905?hl=en)

> This page will help you get to the right place to report content that you would like removed from Google's services under applicable laws. Providing us with complete information will help us investigate your inquiry.
>
> If you have non-legal issues that concern Google's Terms of Service or Product Policies, please visit http://support.google.com

From [Legal Removal Requests](https://support.google.com/legal/answer/3110420?hl=en)

> If you've come across content on Google that may violate the law, let us know, and we'll carefully review the material and consider blocking, removing or restricting access to it. Abusive content on Google's services may also violate [Google's product policies](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/147806?hl=en), so before sending us a legal request, consider flagging the post, image, or video for one of our content teams to review. For more information on our product and privacy policies, our commitment to transparency, and how to submit a valid legal notice to Google, read on below.

Comment: Ruben, thanks for the feedback. I've already filed it with Google's DMCA / legal / abuse page. I've been successful with other sites/takedowns via that method. However, because the link essentially expires between the time I send it and the time they read it, they claim they can't find it. Which is the whole reason the webmaster is doing it -- to make it hard to have content removed. But I'm guessing by removing some parameters or finding the core info, I can provide a URL that is always active to help expedite takedowns. Taking this over to StackOverflow. Have a great day!